# My .wsdl file is downloading but not opening, Parsing WSDL error

Tags: php, nginx, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to read a wsdl file, I get an error:

> Uncaught SoapFault
> exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
> 'http://localhost:8081/soap/news.wsdl' : failed to load external
> entity "http://localhost:8081/soap/news.wsdl" in
> /var/www/app/soap/soap-client.php:22 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/app/soap/soap-client.php(22):
> SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...', Array) #1 {main} thrown
> in /var/www/app/soap/soap-client.php on line 22

Here is my code in server-client.php:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8081/soap/news.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
```

After reading the forums, tried adding the extension "openssl", but the error remains. When I try to open http://localhost:8081/soap/news.wsdl , the file is not opened, but downloaded automatically. I tried spelling in nginx cfg:

```
location ~ \.wsdl$ {
        root /var/www/app;
        default_type application/xml;
        }
```

But that didn't help either.

I think the problem is in the nginx config. My config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

        location ~ \.wsdl$ {
        root /var/www/app;
        default_type application/xml;
    } 
}
```

My WSDL file "news.wsdl" :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<definitions name='News'
             targetNamespace='http://localhost:8081/news'
             xmlns:tns='http://localhost:8081/news'
             xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
             xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
             xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
             xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
             xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

  <message name='getNewsByIdRequest'>
    <part name='id' type='xsd:integer' />   </message>   <message name='getNewsByIdResponse'>
    <part name='item' type='xsd:base64Binary' />   </message>

  <message name='getNewsCountResponse'>
    <part name='count' type='xsd:integer' />   </message>

  <message name='getNewsCountByCatRequest'>
    <part name='cat_id' type='xsd:integer' />   </message>   <message name='getNewsCountByCatResponse'>
    <part name='count' type='xsd:integer' />   </message>


  <portType name='NewsPortType'>
    <operation name='getNewsById'>
      <input message='tns:getNewsByIdRequest' />
      <output message='tns:getNewsByIdResponse' />
    </operation>
    <operation name='getNewsCount'>
      <output message='tns:getNewsCountResponse' />
    </operation>
    <operation name='getNewsCountByCat'>
      <input message='tns:getNewsCountByCatRequest' />
      <output message='tns:getNewsCountByCatResponse' />
    </operation>   </portType>

  <binding name='NewsBinding' type='tns:NewsPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http' />
    <operation name='getNewsById' />
    <operation name='getNewsCount' />
    <operation name='getNewsCountByCat' />   </binding>

  <service name='NewsService'>
    <port name='NewsPort' binding='NewsBinding'>
      <soap:address location='http://localhost:8081/soap/soap-server.php' />
    </port>   
   </service> 
</definitions>
```

By the way, I tried opening another person's .wsdl file. He was fine. Please help me with this problem, I've already broken my head :(

Comment: https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/1761561884?version=1

Comment: @Sammitch: All items passed, but one error 
Style Conformity: ERROR
NewsBinding
Could not detect the 'use' for the operations of binding NewsBinding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i took few days to figure out how to fix it.

My code works fine in DEV but not in PROD.

The problem was because of libxml Version:

- **In dev:** libxml Version   2.7.6
- **In prod:** libxml Version  2.9.1

( *You can check your version echoing: phpinfo();* )

To resolve the problem try to:

Add this: **libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);** before loading your external xml

This function disable/enable the ability to load external entities. And it seems to be disabled by default since libxml 2.9.0

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php

Good luck!